# Store: one click checkout?

Tags: expresso-store

Is there a way to configure Store so that it redirects the customer to the checkout page upon adding an item to a shopping cart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a return parameter on the product tag to redirect the user to whatever page you want. If your checkout url was `example.com/checkout` you would have something along the lines of

```
{exp:store:product return="checkout" entry_id="{entry_id}"}
```

From the [docs](https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/product_tag.html#return_path)

> **return="path"**
>
> This parameter is optional. It will redirect the user to
> the specified page after the form is submitted - such as the Checkout
> page. If no redirect is specified, the form will display the current
> page (useful if you just wish to update a sidebar cart)

Comment: Is it possible to have two `{exp:store:product}` tags within the same channel entry loop? One to be configured for "add to cart" and the other "add to cart and checkout"? How do I provide buttons for both scenarios for each entry?

Comment: While I haven't tested it should be possible you would just need to add 2 separate `{exp:store:product}` tag pairs with different returns paths set and if your products have modifiers those would need to be duplicated to along with quantity of you were wanting to allow users to add more then a single item to the cart. The product tags also could not be nested within each other or it would cause issues